# How do I jump to the last sexp at the current nesting level?

Tags: navigation

Suppose I have this structure:

```
((1 2 3)
 (4 5 6)
 (7 8))
```

I can move backward and forward sexp-by-sexp (one-by-one) with `backward-sexp` and `forward-sexp`.

However, I often have dozens of sexps to navigate, and I am looking for a command that takes me directly to the last (or first) sexp at that level. A command that takes me to the beginning or end of the enclosing sexp also works.

To illustrate using the example above, pretend I have the cursor positions `start-a`, `end-a`, `start-b`, and `end-b`.

What I want is to jump from `start-a` to `end-a`, and from `start-b` to `end-b`.

```
(start-a (start-b 1 2 3 end-b)
 (4 5 6)
 (7 8) end-a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't exist a ready-made function, you can create one:

```
(defun jump-to-last-sexp()
  "Jump to the last sexp of a sexp at current level"
   (interactive)
  (let ((pt(point)) (fwpt (progn(thing-at-point--end-of-sexp)(point))))
    (while(not(eq pt fwpt))
      (setq pt fwpt fwpt(progn(thing-at-point--end-of-sexp)(point))))))
```

and bind it to a keystroke

```
(bind-key "C-c C-e" #'jump-to-last-sexp)
```

or any key you like.